# Error PUT Sense/Net REST API

Tags: sensenet

I use a PUT sense/net Rest API to change DisplayName of a content. That request is success but the file size change to 0. So i cannot download that file.

Please give the way to resolve this problem

Answer (score 3):

PUT means that DisplayName field will be set and the rest of the fields will be cleared. Use PATCH instead of PUT.
Check [this article](http://wiki.sensenet.com/OData_REST_API#Modifying_one_or_more_fields_of_an_entity)